# What is a na-baron?

Tags: terminology, powder-mage

In *Promise of Blood* (2013) -- the first book in Brian McClellan's *[The Powder Mage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Powder_Mage_trilogy)* trilogy -- there are a couple mentions (I'm not too far in yet) of "na-baron"s. From context, I can figure that it's some kind of nobility, but what specifically is a na-baron?

For context, here's a quote. Unfortunately, its context is rubbish and I'll swap it out for a better one when I find one:

> "You've one mark on your record," Tamas said. "You once punched a na-baron in the face. Broke his jaw. Tell me about that."

I don't know of the term in the real world and a hasty Google search seems to agree.

If the question can be answered from context in any of the trilogy or the supplementary short fiction, and if the evidence details could be stuck in spoiler mark-up, that would be awesome!

Comment: It appears the author has twitter. Perhaps one of our twitter users could persuade him to drop by? :D

Comment: I searched the text of *The Promise of Blood* on Amazon, and I couldn’t find any explanation. Na-barons are mentioned several times, but the very short context that it gave me never clarified what they were beyond what you already know. Searching the next two books on Google books, I couldn’t find any mention of na-barons at all.

Comment: @amarillo That's certainly thorough! Weird that there's no explanation though.

Comment: A Na-baron is one who has made his fortune in the salt mines.

Answer (score 11):

A na-Baron is the next in line to inherit the title.

Example from **Dune**.

> Gurney Halleck: "It's the na-Baron...Baron now that the old man's dead."

I suspect that Mr. McClellan took the term from *Dune*.

I searched in [Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=na-baron) for the term, but did not get a hit.

I also looked in Google Ngram; the word Baron occurs most frequently from 1800 to 1850, but there was no hit there for Na-Baron going back 400 years in German, French, and English: this would indicate that the word probably does not really exist.

Comment: But is that specific to the Dune universe? Was it coined by the author of Dune and is there anything to suggest it means the same in The Powder Mage?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that series. Can you give me a link or context?

Comment: sure I'll edit one in

Comment: The word "Na-baron" doesn't appear in 'The Count of Monte Cristo'.

Comment: @Richard Thanks. Maybe it's in one of Brent Weeks books. McClellan says he loves his stuff.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that "na-Baron" is specific to the Duniverse but how to \[citation needed\] it? It's one of those constructions involving german and french words that Herbert was fond of like "Combine Honnête Ober Advancer Mercantiles". Probably should be "nah-Baron" (near Baron) but that looks weird in english.

Answer (score 6):

Frank Herbert kindly provides us with a definition at the end of the Dune novel. The na-Baron is described as the ['heir *apparent*'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_apparent) or 'heir *designate*', as distinguished from the ['heir *presumptive*'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_presumptive) (who can be displaced by the birth of a more eligible person).

> **Na-: a prefix meaning “nominated” or “next in line.” Thus: na-Baron
> means heir apparent to a barony.**
>
> <sub><sup>Dune: Appendix - Terminology of the Imperium</sup></sub>

We see it described in-universe the same way.

> Which left the Beast alone and in charge.
>
> He was technically the na-Baron, the heir apparent to House Harkonnen,
> though the Baron had often threatened to change his mind and cede
> control to young Feyd-Rautha. Unless Rabban could find some way to
> prove himself invaluable.
>
> <sub><sup>*[Dune: House Corrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune:_House_Corrino)*</sup></sub>

> Smiling at his parents’ horrified expressions, Rabban said, “In the
> same manner that he has already adopted me. I am his heir-designate,
> the na-Baron. I’m a Harkonnen as pure and proper as the Baron
> himself.” He extended his thick arms. The troops kept their weapons
> steady, but Emmi backed closer to the fire. “See, you have nothing to
> worry about.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Dune: House Harkonnen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune:_House_Harkonnen)</sup></sub>

Brian McClellan seems to be using it in much the same vein.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a thorough google search and the only thing it comes up with is references to Dune.

A Wikia page for Dune say that -

> Na-Baron is the title given to a Baron's heir apparent.

Otherwise I am not finding any other Na-Baron's.

Comment: What's with the wizards answering this question ;) yah that's annoying. I'm guessing he nicked it from dune

Comment: @MacCooper Well we are all knowing aren't we? lol ;p That is my guess... Even went and got a long long list of titles from all sorts of countries (and times in history) and no luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

@Rincewind Hi, I know it has been eight years, but I think I could add something. In Balearic Catalan exists the feminine article "na" which can be used informally before feminine people's names, or in a formal context as a courtesy title for women, for example: La senyora Na Teresa Pujols (The lady Na Teresa Pujols).